# Form , HasError, AlertError (export and import) was not found in vform

Tags: vue-component, laravel-8, laravel-mix-vue3

Form , HasError, AlertError (export and import)  was not found in vform
When I use the following code. It's not working:

```
import { Form, HasError, AlertError } from 'vform'
Vue.component(HasError.name, HasError)
Vue.component(AlertError.name, AlertError)
```

When I use the following code. It's working:

```
import  Form from 'vform'
import  HasError from 'vform'
import  AlertError from 'vform'
Vue.component(HasError.name, HasError)
Vue.component(AlertError.name, AlertError)
```

Why does the first process not working? I'm using laravel 8 and vue 3